# Server client message verification

Tags: c, sockets, unix, tcp

I have a question about communication between a client and a server. I would like to send data over a TCP unix socket (I know how to do this), and I don't know what is the best practises to test if the message sent is ready to be read entirely (not block per block).

Thus, I'm thinking of this

1. The client send the data printf(3) formatted, the message is written in a string and sent.
2. The server receive the message, but how to be sure the message if full ? Do I need to loop until the message is complete ?

So my idea is to use a code (or checksum maybe ?) that will be prepended and appended to the message like this :

**[verification code]** my_long_data_formatted **[verification code]**

And then, the server tries to read the data until the second verification code is read and succesfully checked.

Is this a proper solution for client / server communication ? If yes, what do you advise me for the verfications boundaries ?

Comment: If you send the message size along then you know how much to read and thus when you are done reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, so I don't think there is a "proper" solution.  Your solution will probably work.  The one note of caution is that you need to make sure the valiation code you chose is not sent as part of the data in the message.  If that is the case, you will detect that the message is complete, even though it is really not the end of the message.  If that is not possible to know what the data will look like, you may need to try a different technique.

From your description, it sounds like your messages are variable length.  Another way would be to make all the messages the same length, that way you know how much data is to be read each time to get a complete message.

Another way would be to send over the length of the message first (such as a binary 32 bit number) which indicates the number of bytes to be read until the end of the message.  You read this first to get the amount of data, and then read that amount from the socket.

If you had a set number of messages where the length was the same each time, you could assign a number to each message and send that number first, which you could then read.  With that information you can determine how much data is to be read based on the assigned number to the message.

What you select to use for a solution will probably be based on factors like if messages are varaible or fixed in length and/or do you need to send additional information with the data.  In this case, you might have a mixture where you send a fixed length header, which contains the information about the data which follows; either in length or the type of data which follows.

Answer (score 4):

TCP already has a built-in checksum/verification. So if the message was received, it was received correctly.

Typically then, the only thing you have to worry about is figuring out how long the message is. This is done either by sending the message length at the beginning or by putting a termination character or sequence at the end.

To make sure both the sender and receiver are "on the same page" so to speak, the receiver will typically send back a response after the message was received, even if that response only says "OK".

Examples of this technique include HTTP, SMTP, POP3, IMAP, and many others.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but even if the message is bigger as the TCP max packet I can read carefully the data (prepended by the size to read) ?

Comment: @user840599 TCP is a stream-oriented protocol, not a packet-oriented protocol. The details of how it gets packetized are hidden from the programmer. But yes, you typically do loop on your receive call pushing data into a buffer until you have enough to satisfy your requirements

Comment: Thank you, I see. Now I just need to write a good mechanism to read until the message is full. I think a thread can do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to establish an **application-level protocol** that would tell you somehow where application messages start and end in the byte stream provided to you by TCP (and then maybe how connected parties proceed with the conversation).

Popular choices are:

- Fixed-length messages. Works well with binary data and is very simple.
- Variable-size messages with fixed format or size header that tells exact size (and maybe type) of the rest of the message. Works with both binary and text data.
- Delimited messages - some character(s) like new-line or `\x1` are special and denote message boundaries. Best with text data.
- Self-describing messages like XML, or S-expressions, or ASN.1.